# Making paper-aligned html to be used with WKHTMLTOPDF

Tags: javascript, html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to implement a report engine using WKHTMLTOPDF and I'm having trouble aligning the content with paper edges.

Consider I'm setting the paper size to A4 and print margins to zero like this:

```
wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --load-error-handling ignore --orientation Portrait --page-size A4 --margin-top 0 --margin-bottom 0 --margin-left 0 --margin-right 0
```

Now I would like to make a report in which the content is not cut off by paper edges. e.g. my content is consisted of tables and cells and I don't want a cell to be splitted into two pages. CSS2 has a feature specifically for this, `page-break-inside:avoid`, but I know no browser that supports it, and webkit is no exception.

Then I thought if I knew how long actually is an A4 paper in WKHTMLTOPDF then I can write some Javascript to align rows by resizing them. Since there was no mean to tell the actual millimeters within CSS to fill an A4 paper completely, I had no choice but to use error and trial. Finally I managed to tune the css height (`height: 290.245261mm`) so the page content fills up an A4 paper vertically. This height is set for a DIV with absolute positioning and top and left set to zero. All the effective paddings and margins are also set to zero (HTML, BODY, ...).

All was fine until I realized the severity of situation when number of pages grows. So I put ten of full-page DIVs within my HTML and to my surprise it printed 11 pages. With one tiny row of pixels at the beginning of the 11th page.

So, here's my question: Has anyone come up with a solution to align HTML content with paper edges when converting an HTML using WKHTMLTOPDF? And I'm using WKHTMLTOPDF 0.11.0 rc1.

Answer (score 1):

*(Though this is an old question, people still ask so...)*

The best fix is to update your `wkhtmltopdf` tool.

The bug you describe was fixed in [version 0.12](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0120-2014-02-06) and table rows are no longer split into two pages ( as mentioned in the linked changelog:

- **[qt]** prevent page breaks in table rows

I am using the same library for multiple projects and this saved me, even if I had to custom compile it back then.